# Is it possible to configure alerts for exceeding google API quotas?

Tags: google-api

I've been using the [Google Cloud Console](https://cloud.google.com/console) to manage API keys and settings.  Some of the keys will be for commercially released products, so obviously we need to keep track of our API call quota.

Is it possible to set up alerts (email or otherwise) for nearing or exceeding the quota?  We would prefer not to wait until a support request comes in, or try to remember to check the console every day.

Comment: Did you ever find any information about this?